# What is the difference between switchLatest and flatmapLastest in RxJs

Tags: javascript, scala, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I am having difficulty in seeing the difference between switchLatest and flatmapLatest in RxJs with the difference being one flattens a nested observable affer the fact like in scala whilst the other is the equivalent of doing it before returning the new flattened collection?

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.flatMapLatest(func)` is equivalent to `.map(func).switchLatest()`, where `func` outputs an observable.

Comment: For future readers: `switchLatest` is deprecated and renamed to just `switch` in RxJs implemenation. Also `flatMapLatest` is called `switchMap` in many RX implementations (Java, Groovy, Kotlin, Scala, RxJS5), which clearly show what it do: `map()` then `switch()`.